# How to plot on secondary y-Axis with plotly express

Tags: python, express, plotly, yaxis, plotly-express

How do I utilize plotly.express to plot multiple lines on two yaxis out of one Pandas dataframe?

I find this very useful to plot all columns containing a specific substring:

```
    fig = px.line(df, y=df.filter(regex="Linear").columns, render_mode="webgl")
```

as I don't want to loop over all my filtered columns and use something like:

```
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattergl(x=df["Time"], y=df["Linear-"]))
```

in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks vestland for the suggestion but in the question and answer plotly express isn't utilized at all. Instead it uses multiple times go.Scatter( x=df["x"], y=df["y"]).

What I wanted through plotly express is px.line(df, y=<list of column labels>) to plot all specific columns at once. Plotly express does not support adding lines straight to secondary_y by now. Therefore the indirect approach as shown in my answer below.

I will clarify this in the question soon.

For one very familiar with plotly this might be a nobrainer. For me it took some time :)

Comment: You seem to be right!

Answer (score 59):

It took me some time to fiddle this out, but I feel this could be useful to some people.

```
# import some stuff
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create some data
df = pd.DataFrame()
n = 50
df["Time"] = np.arange(n)
df["Linear-"] = np.arange(n)+np.random.rand(n)
df["Linear+"] = np.arange(n)+np.random.rand(n)
df["Log-"] = np.arange(n)+np.random.rand(n)
df["Log+"] = np.arange(n)+np.random.rand(n)
df.set_index("Time", inplace=True)

subfig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

# create two independent figures with px.line each containing data from multiple columns
fig = px.line(df, y=df.filter(regex="Linear").columns, render_mode="webgl",)
fig2 = px.line(df, y=df.filter(regex="Log").columns, render_mode="webgl",)

fig2.update_traces(yaxis="y2")

subfig.add_traces(fig.data + fig2.data)
subfig.layout.xaxis.title="Time"
subfig.layout.yaxis.title="Linear Y"
subfig.layout.yaxis2.type="log"
subfig.layout.yaxis2.title="Log Y"
# recoloring is necessary otherwise lines from fig und fig2 would share each color
# e.g. Linear-, Log- = blue; Linear+, Log+ = red... we don't want this
subfig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(line=dict(color=t.marker.color)))
subfig.show()
```

[image: Finished graph]

The trick with

```
subfig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(line=dict(color=t.marker.color)))
```

I got from nicolaskruchten here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60031260

Comment: If you're not happy with the colors resulting from `for_each_trace`, it's possible to update them individually. This, `subfig.data[0].line.update({'color': 'black'})`, updates the first line to black, for example.

Comment: How can I share guide lines between y axis? two y axis should have different tick but same guide line/

Answer (score 4):

Thank you derflo and vestland!  I really wanted to use Plotly Express as opposed to Graph Objects with dual axis to more easily handle DataFrames with lots of columns.  I dropped this into a function.  Data1/2 works well as a DataFrame or Series.

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd

def plotly_dual_axis(data1,data2, title="", y1="", y2=""):
    # Create subplot with secondary axis
    subplot_fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

    #Put Dataframe in fig1 and fig2
    fig1 = px.line(data1)
    fig2 = px.line(data2)
    #Change the axis for fig2
    fig2.update_traces(yaxis="y2")

    #Add the figs to the subplot figure
    subplot_fig.add_traces(fig1.data + fig2.data)

    #FORMAT subplot figure
    subplot_fig.update_layout(title=title, yaxis=dict(title=y1), yaxis2=dict(title=y2))

    #RECOLOR so as not to have overlapping colors
    subplot_fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(line=dict(color=t.marker.color)))


    return subplot_fig
```

**UPDATE:**

This is great for creating a plot with dual axis, but I also wanted to call out the behavior of gridlines and zero points.  These y-axis are totally separate.  So by default, the zero points will not align (see red box) and neither will the gridlines:

[image]

You may be able to align the zeroes fairly easily by utilizing `rangemode = 'tozero'` in your yaxis dictionaries when applying a layout.  See [the layout-yaxis Plotly Documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-rangemode).  However, this won't work if you have negative values.

The good folk at plotly are currently working on gridline alignment.  There are some great examples of this at work in [this Github repo](https://github.com/VictorBezak/Plotly_Multi-Axes_Gridlines).