# Is there a convention in using dict vs curly brace initialisation when using Plotly?

Tags: python, dictionary, plotly, conventions

The docs for Plotly and many answers on Stack Overflow trend toward using

```
dict(foo=bar)
```

instead of

```
{'foo':'bar'}
```

Is there a particular reason for this preference? I've been told in the past that curly brace initialisation is preferred.

---

Some examples pulled randomly:

[Plotly multi axis docs](https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/#multiple-y-axes-and-plotly-express)
[image: Plotly multi axis docs]

[Adding secondary y axis to bar line chart in ploty express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67407291/adding-secondary-y-axis-to-bar-line-chart-in-ploty-express)
[image: Adding secondary y axis to bar line chart in ploty express]

Comment: Both of these are really just matters of opinion. The *literal* form will be faster, although that isn't usually a concern. It also accepts any kind of keys instead of just string keys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between using a dict literal and a dict constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610606/is-there-a-difference-between-using-a-dict-literal-and-a-dict-constructor) (Although you mention plotly, this isn't specific to plotly, as both return a dict)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Python's naming convention

One reason why `dict(foo=bar)` may be preferred to `{'foo':'bar'}`:

In `{'foo':'bar'}`, the key `foo` can be initialized to be any string. For example,

```
mydict = {'1+1=':2}
```

is allowed.

`dict(foo=bar)` ensures the dictionary keys to be valid identifiers. For example,

```
mydict = dict('1+1='=2)
```

will return error `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`.

### Non-string key

The second reason may be when you want the key to be not a string. For example, `dict(a = 2)` is allowed, but `{a: 2}` is not. You would want `{'a': 2}`.